# Would "editmeta" ever return a different response for two issues in the same project, of the same issue type?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

My goal is to retrieve a list of fields for an issue type that belongs to a JIRA project.  JIRA API provides a method to retrieve "createmeta" for any issue type:

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/ondemand/#api/2/issue-getCreateIssueMeta

This returns the list of fields on the "create" screen.

But there isn't a similar abstract method to retrieve the fields from the "edit" screen.  The only method JIRA API provides is issue-specific:

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/ondemand/#api/2/issue-getEditIssueMeta

Why isn't there a method to retrieve "edit" fields that doesn't require me to provide a specific issue key?  Is there a fundamental reason for this - e.g., issues of the same issue type and within the same project can somehow have different "edit" fields?

Answer (score 0):

Got official word from the JIRA PM / Dev team:

> Yes, issues can have different editmeta, even if they of the same
>   issue type in the same issue type scheme. JIRA is a highly pluggable
>   system, editmeta contains information about JIRA built-in fields and
>   custom fields which may be developed by 3rd party. While JIRA built-in
>   fields return the same editmeta (for the moment) we don't know what
>   3rd party custom fields do, they have option to return different
>   metadata depending on the issue.